# Possible to download stats of all pokemon in bag on Android?

Tags: pokemon-go, android

I want to calculate the IV of all of my pokemon as per this site [here](https://pokeassistant.com/main/ivcalculator). Is there any way to grab all of the game data needed for say Android (ie pokemon name, cp, hp, dust)?

I'm kind of curious to see whether I can automate the process but am stuck at this point. Is it possible that this game data is cached somewhere on the device? If so where would it be stored? Is there an API that can be used to retrieve it?

Answer (score 3):

I dont know how the game saves the data. But there is an unoffical App that can calculate your Pokémon bag completely. It's called [Pokiimap](https://github.com/kiideveloper/pokiimap).
In this App you can access your Pokébag and it automatically shows your Pokémons IV, the IV in percent, the CP, the max CP and the candies needed to level up.

But keep in mind: manipulating or accessing the game data in different ways than the App is against their Terms of Services and there is a chance that you will be banned - that also counts for extracting the data manually.

Comment: If you need more info on how to use the App, I can answer it here. But everything should be said in the description of the App.

Comment: Cool app, but seems overkill for just getting stats of my own pokemon. Will need to try it after the game starts to get old in case of ban maybe

Comment: Do you know if the "human" version would show some of the stuff you mentioned? Seems to be a bit safer

Comment: The human version disables all options, that effect you main account. So it disables the function `catch`, `loot`, and everything that effects your inventory. So no, this shouldn't work.
But you can just ignore the functions of the app you won't use ;)

Answer (score 1):

Until recently there was a great site called PokeAdvisor where you could see and track all your stats. Unfortunately Niantic shut it down but there is a great alternative: https://pogobag.me/

It does not track as much stats as PokeAdvisor did but is still very decent! However bear in mind that Niantic might take action against this and shut it down sooner or later as well...